# VB.NET 14 Variable variable interpolated string

Tags: .net, vb.net

In VS 2015 / VB.NET 14 you can do some pretty cool stuff with string interoplation for example:

```
Dim str1 As String = "Hello"
Dim dict1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict1.Add("Area", "World")

Dim output As String = $"{str1} {dict1("Area")}"
Console.WriteLine(output)


>Hello World
```

But what if the string format is variable/configurable? How can I do something like this:

```
Dim str1 As String = "Hello"
Dim dict1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict1.Add("Area", "World")

Dim format = getStringFormat()
Dim output As String = $format
Console.WriteLine(output)


>World Hello
```

I am using .NET 4

Answer (score 2):

An interpolated string has to be hard-coded, because it needs to be parsed by the compiler.

My [NString](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NString) library has a [`StringTemplate`](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NString#stringtemplate) class that does something similar to string interpolation, but at runtime rather that at compile time:

```
var joe = new Person { Name = "Joe", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1980, 6, 22) };
string text = StringTemplate.Format("{Name} was born on {DateOfBirth:D}", joe);
```

It's not exactly what you're asking, but it might help.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not forget that interpolated strings are only syntax sugar for `String.Format()`.**

So whenever things need to go more complex, simply return to use of `String.Format()`.

```vb
Dim format1 As String = "{0} {1}"
Dim format2 As String = "{1} {0}"

Dim string1 As String = String.Format(format1, "Hello", "World")
Dim string2 As String = String.Format(format2, "Hello", "World")

' now your case: format string created as result of another format string
Dim stringComplex As String = String.Format(
                                        String.Format("{0} {1}", format1, format2), 
                                        "Hello", 
                                        "World")
```

Or do you think that interpolated string in interpolated string adds any special comfort to your code? I'd say no.

Comment: It would be usefull as the string format is configurable. So when changing the setting using {propA} {propB} instead of {0} {1} would be a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a helper function and pass in the required argument:

```
Public Function GetString(arg1 As String, arg2 As String) As String
    Return $"{arg1} {dict1(arg2)}"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim variables As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
        {"Country", "USA"},
        {"IpAddress", "8.8.8.8"},
        {"evtCount", 5},
        {"username", "Admin"}
    }

    Dim template As String = "{IpAddress}, {country}, {username}, {evtCount} DNS queries. {Country} (different case...)"
    Console.WriteLine(template)
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine(VariableStringInterpolation(template, variables))

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

Public Function VariableStringInterpolation(
                                   template As String,
                                   variables As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                                   ) As String

    Dim returValue As String = template

    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In variables
        returValue = ReplaceCaseInsensitive(returValue, "{" & item.Key + "}", item.Value.ToString)
    Next

    Return returValue

End Function

Public Function ReplaceCaseInsensitive(template As String, target As String, replacement As String) As String

    Dim returValue As String = template
    Dim rx As Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

    rx =
        New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(
        target,
        Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    returValue = rx.Replace(template, replacement)

    Return returValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

interpolated strings are a  "Compile time" feature.   So they won't work with runtime variables.

Consider this code:

```
Dim f As New Test With {.A = 1, .B = 2, .C = 3}
Dim str = $"{f.A},{f.B},{f.C}"
```

The second line compiles to this IL:

```
IL_001f: ldstr "{0},{1},{2}"
IL_0024: ldloc.0
IL_0025: callvirt instance int32 GeneralTest/Test::get_A()
IL_002a: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_002f: ldloc.0
IL_0030: callvirt instance int32 GeneralTest/Test::get_B()
IL_0035: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_003a: ldloc.0
IL_003b: callvirt instance int32 GeneralTest/Test::get_C()
IL_0040: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0045: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,  object,  object,  object)
```

Translated back to VB this would be:

```
Dim str As String = String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", f.A, f.B, f.C)
```

This means that interpolated strings do not exist at runtime!  You can't use the funk in user adjustable variables..

I am actually happy about that..   otherwise this would be a MAJOR 'code execution injection security hole!'